# Get a google places autocomplete status

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

How to get a status in google places autocomplete search.. If i type something in google places autocomplete textbox and if the places is not there then how to make an alert that the place is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this.

```
var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
```